# python import csv function

Tags: python, list, function, return-value

Attempting to learn python and am starting off by simply trying to duplicate some powershell scripts I use for daily productivity tasks.  I'd like to ask you folks why this method doesn't work in python:

```
def csvIn(path):
    import csv
    with open(path) as myFile:
        csv = csv.reader(myFile)
    return csv

a = csvIn('C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/DL/add.csv')

for row in a:
    print(row)
```

I'm trying to write a function that imports the CSV file and puts its output into a list (array). The whole thing works if I call the import csv outside of a function call.  When I try it from inside the function, I get this: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

Comment: Maybe because you have `csv` as a variable as well as a module?

Comment: That's not why, try renaming the 2nd csv name to be csv2 or something, you still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the with is a context manager, so when the program reaches the return line, the file has been closed.

Constructive suggestion would be to just roll it into one:

```
import csv
PATH = 'C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/DL/add.csv'
with open(PATH) as myFile:
   h_csv = csv.reader(myFile)
   for row in h_csv:
      print(row)
```

EDIT: as requested here's an example of it as a function but without the with:

```
import csv

def csvIn(path):
    myFile = open(path)
    h_csv = csv.reader(myFile)
    return h_csv

a = csvIn('C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/DL/add.csv')

for row in a:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Completely agree.  As I said above, it all works fine when I do it that way.  Was just wondering how it can be done with a function in python.  Is there an alternate way to accomplish it without using the "with"?

Comment: Sure just use the open builtin without the with, see my edit. Not sure you really want a function that returns a handle to a file object because it'll leave it open in outer scope. Probably better to have it return an iterator - that's the best of both worlds - treat it like a list but don't use much memory.

Comment: That does work.  Upvoted and marked as the answer.  Thank you.